# Jmeter basics with some sample

Tags: java, jmeter

What is Jmeter ? What is it's use and where can I find some usage examples?

Please let me know how to use it to test performance.

Comment: Have you read about it or even tryed it? Try it out for yourself, and then ask more specific questions here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked at [the official site](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), or [the user manual](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/index.html)? The latter is quite detailed.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it but any sample program would really help.

Comment: There are many samples in the user guide. Is there something specific you are looking for help with? The best place to get an introduction is from the project's documentation.

Comment: @Mahesh Patil matt b is correct, you should definitely check out the JMeter site, there are lots of good examples for all of JMeter's functions. I found them extremely useful a few weeks back when I had to learn how to use JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

you can get useful samples from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(these samples are provided by jmeter official site).

Also the official site provide [a detailed manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html).

Jmeter is a powerful tool, and if you are using it for performance test, I recommend you take a look at this article. There are many tips in it, also you can find many other useful information from [the official site](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

And I have a suggestion, that is when you want to learn or use something new, take full  advantage of the official site, you can get a lot there.